# Django:: How to manage large number of connections

Tags: python, django

I have a webpage, which will access a db every 1 sec. Its a remote db. Eventually i see its becomes very slow to go to another link

SO if 100 users open the same page then 100 connection every sec. So the navigation is getting blocked.

Any idea how to takle this thing

Comment: to avoid these database access too frequently use cache memory to store common or less changing data. use memcache or reddis

Comment: did you use the connection pool for the steady connection or creating a connection everytime? and what database you are using?